# 403 Forbidden while doing delete request. Spring boot rest api

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, http, security

So i have backend in java and frontend in Angular. While im sending delete request to my spring boot rest endpoint im getting 403 code. 
Angular sends first OPTIONS request and it returns this 403 so DELETE request not happens. 
Additionaly GET and POST works fine.

I have tried disable csrf but it didnt wokred. Also im using it in my browser so i shouldnt disabling this. In soapUI DELETE works fine.

This is my security config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AuthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value(value = "${auth0.apiAudience}")
    private String audience;
    @Value(value = "${auth0.issuer}")
    private String issuer;
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        JwtWebSecurityConfigurer
                .forRS256(audience, issuer)
                .configure(http)
                .cors()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/public").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/private/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/private-scoped").hasAuthority("read:posts");
    }
}
```

I want to do this delete requests.

```
@PostMapping("/private/post/{id}/like")
    public void likePostById(@PathVariable Long id){
        postService.likePostById(id);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/private/post/{id}/like")
    public void unlikePostById(@PathVariable Long id){
        postService.unlikePostById(id);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Whats your delete request look like?

Comment: unlikePostById(post_id: number): Observable<boolean>{
    return this.http.delete<boolean>(environment.api_endpoint+"/private/post/"+post_id+"/like");
  }

Comment: actual request i cant share because its not created. Because OPTIONS request failed

Comment: @123 in soapUI DELETE works well, so request is ok.

Comment: Do you have a proxy infront of the application? Looks like you are trying to access `/backend/private...`, you don't have any ant matchers for `backend`

Comment: i dont have any proxy

Comment: backend is my main matcher. Every request starts with localhost:8080/backend/.....

Comment: i replaced to /backend/private but still dont works

Comment: maybe i need some kind of token  from my angular app? Because if soapui works

Comment: Oh right yeah, if it works from soapui, then it's definitely the other app

Answer (score 1):

In case you are on Spring Boot, you can do this, too:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer()
{
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", 
            "PATCH", "OPTIONS", "HEAD");
        }
    };
}
```

You can add your mappings to a particular url as well.

Comment: You can also use :                                                             CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();          config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("POST", "GET", "PUT", "DELETE"));

Answer (score 0):

I think you limit your request type by

```
HttpMethod.GET
```

in your antMatchers.

Remove this parameter or add one more antiMatcher like:

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"your delete url").permitAll()
```

Comment: I did .antMatchers("/private/**").authenticated() but this doesnt work. I think this is not problem because POST requests works fine.

Comment: Usually, I use .anyRequest().authenticated() for the undefined request in config. I guess if your post just get passed by security? Can you show your urls?

Comment: added in post higher

Comment: i did .anyRequest().authenticated() but still delete request doesnt work properly